# table row not displaying horizontally in Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, cordova-3

Why `tr` tag does not show my buttons horizontally but vertically instead.

Similar code works properly on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uzxWp/)

What am I doing wrong?

here my **HTML**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />

<link href="css/menuprincipale.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header"></div>

    <div data-role="content">

        <table class="clsActionTable">
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                    <button class="clsActionButton" id="idAddButton">Add</button>
                    <button class="clsActionButton" id="idEditButton">Edit</button>
                    <button class="clsActionButton" id="idDeleteButton">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <img src="img/logo.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

here my **CSS**:

```css
.clsActionTable
{
 width: 100%;
 height:20%;
 color: white;
 font-size: smaller;
}

.clsActionButton
{
 width: 180px;
 height:40px;
}

#idActionPlane
{
 left: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
 height:20%;
 width:100%;
 background-color: #4E5A81;
 color: White;
}
```

I am using these:

- Cordova 3.5
- jQuery 1.4
- js
- html5

Comment: add more details for the whole page

Comment: @cracker I added my html header. now I can align my table but css is still no taking effect (In the browser is working properly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: center;">
    <button class="clsActionButton" id="idAddButton">Add</button>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">
    <button class="clsActionButton" id="idEditButton">Edit</button>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">
    <button class="clsActionButton" id="idDeleteButton">Delete</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has this same problem and the good answer above does not work, in my situation removing data-role="table" from the table html in jQuery mobile solved the problem as it does make the table vertical by default. Even better way for sure would be to do this via css.